# R plotting a matrix with row and column names

Tags: r, plot

I read a data in a matrix from a file with row and column names. How do I use R plotting functions to automatically plot all the column series on the Y-axis against row-names on the X-axis and create legends for column-names.

```
data = read.csv(file="sample.csv",head=T,row.names=1)
data
             ES NQ   DJ YAP    FCE ESX    LFT    HS   SNI SXF   STW    CGB
19971006 981.50 NA 8171  NA 3078.0  NA 5371.0 14870 17845  NA 339.9 122.67
19971007 989.50 NA 8232  NA 3071.0  NA 5387.0 14720 17565  NA 334.0 122.65
19971008 989.50 NA 8160  NA 3028.0  NA 5299.0 14880 17630  NA 337.2 122.07
19971009 978.00 NA 8124  NA 2962.0  NA 5264.0 15055 17425  NA 346.8 121.55

# plot ES, NQ, ... series against row-names 19971006,19971007, etc
# create legends for column series ES, NQ, etc..
```

Note that it should be able to treat the row-names  19971006,19971007 as integers and create appropriate gap between ticks (such as 1 year, 6 months, etc). I tried different things but it gets messy and there seems to be no good way to manage the row-names vector when plotting.

Should I use a different data structure to represent my data?

Thanks!

Comment: A solution using native plotting function such as 'plot/curve' is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

here is a solution using reshape and ggplot2:

```
ggplot(
  melt(data.frame(date=as.Date(rownames(data), "%Y%m%d"), data), id.vars="date"),
  aes(date, value, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

1. convert rownames to Date object and bind them to the original data frame
2. reshape the wide format data frame to long format by melt
3. plot it using ggplot2, but you can use other graphic package.

And for multi-panel version, facet_wrap or facet_grid is available:

```
ggplot(
  melt(data.frame(date=as.Date(rownames(data), "%Y%m%d"), data), id.vars="date"),
  aes(date, value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90))
```

And here is a base graphics version:

```
d <- data.frame(date=as.Date(rownames(data), "%Y%m%d"), data)
matplot(d[,1], d[,-1], type="b", pch=1, xaxt="n")
axis(1, d[,1], labels=d[,1])
```

Comment: That works. However, it runs a bit slow as I think it is creating new copies of data. How do I split the graph to contain 2 plots with ggplot? I tried doing par(mfrow=c(2,1)) before running above function but it doesn't work. I need to have a single legend for two similar plots. Does ggplot have flexibility to do this?